# Linux effect of ptrace TRACEME call

Tags: linux, gdb, ptrace

I have the following code. It simply calls `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)` before going into an infinite loop.

I have two issues:

1. After executing the binary, I can't attach with gdb even if I am root.
2. With `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)`, I can't terminate the process with Ctrl-C (`SIGINT`). it simply stops.

Can someone explain what's going on?  Thank you in advance.

PS: I know that most debuggers fork a child which then calls `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)` before `execve`.  No need to remind me of this.

```c
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    printf("my pid : %d\n", getpid());  
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME);


    while(1){
        printf("euid : %d\n", geteuid());
        sleep(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> *after executing this binary, I can't attach gdb even if I am root.*

From `man ptrace`:

> **ERRORS**
>
> *EPERM*  The  specified  process cannot be traced.  This could be
>   because the parent has insufficient privileges (the required
>   capability is CAP_SYS_PTRACE); non-root processes cannot trace
>   processes that they cannot send signals to or those running
>   set-user-ID/set-              group-ID programs, for obvious reasons. 
>   **Alternatively, the process may already be being traced**, or be init(8) (PID 1).

---

> *with ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME), I can't terminate the process with Ctrl-C (SIGINT). it simply stops*.

From `man ptrace`:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> **While  being  traced,  the  child  will  stop  each time a signal is**
>   **delivered**, even if the signal is being ignored.  (The exception is
>   SIGKILL, which has its usual effect.)  The parent will be notified at
>   its next wait(2) and may inspect and  modify  the  child  process
>   while it is stopped.  The parent then causes the child to continue,
>   optionally ignoring the delivered signal (or even delivering a
>   different signal instead).

Comment: A couple of additional notes: `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME)` sets things up so that the parent is the tracer. For any given tracee, only one process at a time can be its tracer. Before another process can become the tracer, the current tracer either needs to call `ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, tracee)` or exit.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, does `PTRACE_TRACEME` actually set the parent as the tracer?  I.e., does the parent not need to `PTRACE_ATTACH`?

Comment: @DanielWalker Yes, that is correct.